# When exactly starts rendering of a HTML DOM node?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, html-rendering, dom-node

Consider the following example:

```
<div class="col-2">Some content</div>
<main>
  <!-- lot of content here, including many images etc. -->
</main>
<div id="lastColumn" class="col-2">Last column content</div>
<script>
  if (localStorage.getItem("lastColumnDisplayed") == "false") {
    document.getElementById("main").style.classList.add("col-10");
    document.getElementById("lastColumn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("main").style.classList.add("col-8");
    document.getElementById("lastColumn").style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Are the elements within the `<main>` already being rendered in the time when the `<script>` is executed? I ask because images and tables within the `<main>` have theirs `width` (i.e. the images are scaled) dependent on the `<main>` width, which is defined by [bootstrap's grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) class `.col-8` or `.col-10`.

Does it have any sense to try to add the class directly when defining the opening `<main>` tag? Example:

```
<div class="col-2">Some content</div>
<script>
document.write('<main class="' + getColumnClass() + '">');
</script>
  <!-- lot of content here, including many images etc. -->
</main>
<div class="col-2">Some content</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: You should probably attach your script logic inisde a window.onload event to be sure that all assets, like images are loaded

Comment: The point is that I want to set the CSS styles yet before anything like images is being loaded.